# Raw SQL to Django ORM queryset conversion

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets, rawsql

Here I have a queryset where I am using raw SQL to get data.

But this approach is not fulfilling my requirements.

I want to convert this query into pure **Django ORM** query

```
queryset = Model.objects.raw("select id,category,count(category) 
as total_orders, count(distinct ra, category) as order_type, 
SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_success_order, 
SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_failed_order 
from table 
group by ra;")
```

How can I do this?

**HOW CAN WE IMPLEMENT** count(distinct ra, category) as order_type in queryset?

My approach

```
  queryset = Model.objects.values('ra').annotate(category=F('category'),\
order_type=Count('ra', 'category', distinct=True),total_orders=Count('category'),\
total_success_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='success')),\
total_failed_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='failed'))).order_by()
```

Problem is how to get the order_type because of this need calculation on other attribute values ... as **order_type=Count('ra', 'category', distinct=True)**  is giving error

Comment: what you have tried so far? You should at least show your efforts.

Comment: This could be usefull 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/
https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Debendra here is my approach queryset = Model.objects.values('ra').annotate(category=F('category'),order_type=Count('ra'),total_orders=Count('category'),total_success_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='success')),total_failed_order=Count('service_status', filter=Q(service_status='failed'))).order_by()      ........... => order_type=Count('ra') here is my prob ...not getting order_type